# Android - How to update Adapter's instance variable when the underlying data changed?

Tags: android

Following code will not work because inside onChanged method, we can not access the this because the two are different object.

How can I solve this problem? Please help me. Thanks.

```
this.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            //this will not work
            this.checkedStates = new ArrayList<CheckboxState>(this.getCount());
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

if the code is inside an adapter and checkedStates is a class field, just use:

```
registerDataSetObserver(this);
```

then let your adapter implements `DataSetObserver`

```
@Override
public void onChanged(){
       super.onChanged();
       checkedStates = new ArrayList<CheckboxState>(getCount());
}
```

Comment: @user3087000 did the answer help?